# Euler systems over abelian number fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Im confused with the following statement:

Coleman’s conjecture concerning circular distribution imply that Euler systems over abelian number fields arise in “an elementary” way from the theory of cyclotomic units.

What is that “elementary way”?

I would appreciate if someone could help.